# ¿Cómo consumir un post con un json que tiene byte[] en el cuerpo en c#?

Tags: c#, api

necesito consumir una api post application/json y enviar el siguiente cuerpo

```
{
    "codigo": 0,
    "tipo": 16,   
    "foto": [-1,-40,-1,-37, 0,67, 0, 8, 6, 6,7, 6, 5, 8, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9,  8, 10, 25, 18, 19]
}
```

Desde SoapUi si vale, pero necesito consumir desde HttpClient en c#

He intentado con crear un objeto

```
public class Objeto() {
 public int codigo{ get; set; }
 public int codSolicitud { get; set; }
 public byte[]foto{ get; set; }
}
```

```
var objeto = new Objecto();
objeto.codigo = 0;
objeto.tipo = 16;
objeto.foto = [1,2,3,4,5]

HttpClient client = new HttpClient()
var res = client.PostAsJsonAsync("url", objeto)
```

Quisiera que por favor me ayduen a resolver este problema que tengo.

De antemano les agradezco la ayuda brindada.

Saludos

Comment: Interesante. Cuando enviaste el `client.PostAsJsonAsync`, cuál fue la respuesta de la API? Hubo mensaje de error? Cómo, **exactamente**, te podemos ayudar?

Comment: y cual fue el problema?

Comment: Me envia un error 500 Internal error server. Lo extraño es que en el ejemplo de la documentación esta así  "archivoFoto": [-1, -5, -30, 50, -8] O sea con números negativos, yo pensé que los bytes no puedes ser negativos. Algún otro tipo de dato que pueda ser?

Answer (score 0):

El inconveniente podria ser el tipo de dato byte, prueba cambiando ese dato a string y en el controlador lo conviertes a base 64 antes de guardarlo, te comento por aca porque aun no me deja stack comentar en la publicacion, perdona que no sea una respuesta exacta.